# Как получить доступ к переменной

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, мобильная-разработка

У меня есть функция в которой мне нужно получить переменную из другой функции. Как это сделать?
Функция -

```
@IBAction func enterIntegersToLabel(_ sender: UIButton) {
     self.firstValue = String(sender.tag - 1)
     let value = label.text = label.text! + firstValue
    }
```

---

Просто нужно было вывести переменную из функции.

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста код в вопрос

Comment: Если вам нужно обратиться к переменной из другой функции, значит у вас проблемы с архитектурой и нужно исправлять логику функций. В функциях нет переменных, к которым можно обращаться снаружи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самый простой способ в вашей ситуации - объявить переменную глобально и обращаться к ней.